GC Dataflow workers can't find my python modules
I've written a python script and built a folder structure for a small ETL application that is meant to run as a Google Cloud Dataflow job.
It works locally and I'm able to load, transform, and offload data to a .csv file. But in Google cloud, after running the script, a job is created in Dataflow and always fails with the same error message:
ModuleNotFoundError" No module named 'gx_reporting_etl_functions
"ModuleNotFoundError" No module named 'gx_reporting_etl_functions'"
This is my folder structure, each of my custom modules have been set up using the command:
python setup.py sdistFolder Structure
This creates a .tar.gz for the packaged module that I can pass as an option to my beam pipeline
I'm supplying options to my beam pipeline by hardcoding them:
Options Screenshot
In the above screenshot I'm supplying the path to my modules as a setup option called extrapackages:
setup_options.extra_packages
Something else of note: the program will send an error for each of the modules the same way I included above, sometimes multiple times (maybe from each time the module is referenced in the code?)
Any insights or things to try appreciated.
thank you
At first I tried running the program without passing the modules, now that I've sent them along, I'm not sure why the dataflow workers can't find them.
I've looked into whether python packages or dataflow packages might be obscuring my custom modules because of conflicting names, hence the names are now unique and specific.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
